# Function which the limit is the same for every point, but the function is not the same for every point

Tags: calculus, limits, examples-counterexamples

Let $L \in \mathbb R$.
Let $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.
$\lim_{x\to x0}f(x)=L$ for every $x0\in \mathbb R$, so there exists $x\in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) \neq L$.

I tried finding such function that for every point the limit is the same, but I couldn't find any function besides constant functions and then the second part of the claim is false.
Maybe this claim is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take$$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x\ne0\\1&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Does it satisfy the first part of the claim? I'm probably missing something

Comment: The first par of the claim is that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L$ for every $x_0\in\Bbb R$. And, indeed, for my function we have $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$ for every $x_0\in\Bbb R$. What's the problem?

Comment: For x0=0, we get ()=1 so lim→0()=1. No?

Comment: No. Are you saying that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ is always equal to $f(x_0)$? How do you define $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$?

Comment: Thanks, my bad.